# Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении "Спросить как дела?"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли оставить запятую в предложении "Спросить как дела?" по правилам пунктуации?

Answer (score 1):

Возможный диалог:

**— Чего звонишь?**

**— Спросить, как дела.**

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении (СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным перед союзным слово КАК.